# JAX-WS: Adding Outbound Headers to Service Call

Tags: jax-ws

I have the following client...

```
@WebService(name = "MyService", targetNamespace = "http://namespace")
@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)
@XmlSeeAlso({
  ObjectFactory.class
})
public interface MyService{
  ....
}
```

Another class

```
public MyService getService(){
    URL aURL = new MyHelper().getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(myURL);
    QName qname = new QName("http://xml.othersite.net/MyService/", "MyService");
    return super.getPort(qname, MyService.class);
}
```

How do I set the outbound SOAP headers for the MyService object returned by the previous.

Answer (score 0):

I have a working code that uses sun internal API. It's not good practice, but it works well.

```
WSBindingProvider bp = (WSBindingProvider) service;
bp.setOutboundHeaders(getHeaders());
```